Why the wait to buy Marath HaMachpelah area
Why did Avraham Avinu wait till Sarah Immeinu's death to buy the area of Marath HaMachpelah?
It was known to be a special place to him, so it would make sense that he would have tried to acquire it the moment he had liquid cash in hand. Does anyone know of any info that shows that he tried to acquire that area before hand?

According to Middle East laws (such as Hamurabi code) people of one nation could not sell their land to foreigners at all, as it belonged to the nation. I.e. Avraham could only make such a purchase in extenuating circumstances, for example, after rescue of king of Sodom.

The background is mentioned in the Zohar 1:127b
It notes there that even though Avraham desired the cave before Sarah died he only made a move to buy it when Sarah died so that they would not take advantage of his interest. When Sarah died he realised the time was right to claim it. Had Efron seen in the cave what Avraham saw he would never had sold it.
As a result, Avraham acted with wisdom, he did not ask for the cave but rather requested:

תְּנ֨וּ לִ֤י אֲחֻזַּת־קֶ֙בֶר֙ עִמָּכֶ֔ם
Grant me an estate for a burial site with you (Bereishis 23:4)


The Malbim (footnote to his commentary to Bereishis 23:20) has a fascinating explanation about why the Torah makes such a big deal about the purchase - that Avraham wanted thereby to demonstrate the fundamental principles of the eternity of the soul and of resurrection (and that therefore the deceased can't just be buried anywhere; he further explains that the layout of the cave, "a lower floor and an upper one above it," symbolizes earthly life and the spiritual realms that surmount it).
Since at Sarah's death "everyone stoppped their work and came to pay their respects to Sarah" (Rashi on 23:10), Avraham may have waited for just such an opportunity, when he could publicize these points to the widest audience possible.

I haven’t seen the  question  addressed explicitly but seeing how the Rishonim explain the words גֵּֽר־וְתוֹשָׁ֥ב אָֽנֹכִ֖י עִמָּכֶ֑ם seems to provide the answer. He did not have  easy ability to buy the property  an earlier date. Prior to his reaching תוֹשָׁ֥ב status which he didn’t necessarily have all along  (he also calls himself  גֵּֽר) they would not have sold real estate to him while viewing him as a foreign  investor.  Even if he would have bought it he would have had difficulty making it into a burial spot later on anyway. The Chizkuni says the reason he assembled everyone and told them what he is looking to do with the property  instead of just dealing with Efron is because he needed permission from everyone to turn a plot of land into a burial spot. (they must have had zoning laws back then too). Such permission would  be a lot easier to get as an actual resident currently looking to bury a  relative than it would be as a stranger who isn’t sure he is going to remain there but is looking to bury someone there at a unknown future date.
Rashi says on the words  גֵּֽר־וְתוֹשָׁ֥ב אָֽנֹכִ֖י עִמָּכֶ֑ם that he didn’t have to buy it all. Hashem gave him all of Eretz Yisroel. Had they refused to sell it, he would taken due to his legal ownership  rights. Therefore buying it was probably never of any importance to him.
